# why error print after console.log in microtask

Tags: javascript, event-loop, throw

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QfXe.png)
why number **2** print before throw
i think throw is a macrotask!!!

the intersting things i find is error tip in chrome devtool breakpoint!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pI6i.png)
why??
in my work, macrotask is first execute, then, microtask run before next macrotask, throw is in sync!
so did I get it wrong?

Comment: Provide code and text here as text, not as links to images.

Comment: The "paused on promise rejection" is because the code executed from the console is actually ran as an `async` function. This is completely unrelated to the previous line. As for why the error is shown after the resolved promise log, that can probably be seen as a bug, you may open an issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/wizard but that only affects the console, and one should probably not expect any standard behavior in the console (for instance they also do allow multiple same `const` declaration.

Comment: (Also note that they do expose this behavior since at least M85)